# Lazarus error "External: SIGSEGV" on variable increment?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I got a problem in my Lazarus project: everytime I want to use a function it throws the above error (`External: SIGSEGV`). I don't know what that means, but some debugging showed me, that this is the code, causing the error:

```
class function TUtils.AsStringArray(const Strs:TStrings): TStringArray;
var
  s:string;
  i:integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Strs.Count);
  i := 1;
  for s in Strs do
  begin
    Result[i] := s;
    i := i + 1;
  end;
end;
```

And the definitions

```
TStringArray = array of string; 

TUtils = class
  public
    [...]
    class function AsStringArray(const Strs:TStrings): TStringArray; static;
end;
```

The exception occurs after `i := i + 1;`. I would be really thankful if you could help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic arrays such as `TStringArray = array of string;` are zero-based; your code uses it as 1-based and raises access violation.

You should replace `i := 1;` by `i := 0;`

Comment: It fixed the previous error, but it either revealed another one or it created a new one. The assembler shows this command: `00407189 8b12                     mov    (%edx),%edx`

Answer (score 0):

To the second Problem, it is because you are accesing to the index i, wich at the start it is 1 that is why you have the problem, the range of the array is determined by "length - 1", so if your length is 1, then your range is 0. So to solve the problem in your for loop you have to put `Result[i-1] := s;` like this you acces the index you really want.

More of this on http://wiki.freepascal.org/Dynamic_array